# How to loop through properties of objects in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a method which gets the values of the properties of an object and appends some commas to it. I want to make this generinc so i can use it with other objects.

```
            foreach (var row in rows.ToList())
            {
                sbResult.Append(
                    delimiter + row.MediaName + delimiter + separator +
                    delimiter + row.CountryName + delimiter + separator +
                    delimiter + row.ItemOverRideDate + delimiter + separator +
                    delimiter + row.Rating + delimiter + separator +
                    delimiter + row.BatchNo + delimiter + separator +
                    delimiter + row.NoInBatch + delimiter + separator +
                    delimiter + row.BatchDate + delimiter + separator +
                    delimiter + row.DataType + delimiter + separator +
                    delimiter + row.ByLine + delimiter + separator +
                    delimiter + row.IssueNo + delimiter + separator +
                    delimiter + row.Issue + delimiter + separator +
                    delimiter + row.MessageNo + delimiter + separator +
                    delimiter + row.Message + delimiter + separator +
                    delimiter + row.SourceName + delimiter + separator +
                    delimiter + row.SourceType + delimiter + separator);

                //end of each row
                sbResult.AppendLine();
            }
```

I have tried using `var rowData = row.GetType().GetProperties();` but it only returns the property itself and I dont know how to get the value of the property.

Comment: I would recommend that you store properties as a data structure (such as a Dictionary or ArrayList) if you want to iterate over them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Type.GetProperties` returns a collection of [`PropertyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx), you follow that up by calling [`PropertyInfo.GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s562whf.aspx). Here's how you can do that (and all the rest together) with LINQ:

```
var line = string.Join(
             row.GetType().GetProperties()
              .Select(pi => pi.GetValue(row))
              .Select(v => delimiter + v.ToString() + delimiter),
             separator);
```

However, you might want to reconsider your approach. This code will break if `GetProperties` fetches static properties or indexers along with "normal" properties; it also requires that the code be run with full trust (otherwise no reflection is possible). And finally, it's going to be **slow** because a) reflection is inherently slow and b) it will keep reflecting on the same things over and over again without caching any of the information it has already discovered.

In addition to the above potential problems, if there is even a remote chance that you will later want to filter what gets printed out it is probably better to encapsulate this logic inside a (`virtual`?) method on `row` and just do something like

```
sbResult.AppendLine(row.SerializeAsLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = instance
    .GetType()
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Select(z => string.Format("{0}: {1}\n", z.Name, z.GetValue(instance, null)));

string res = string.Concat(values);
```

Where `instance` is the instance of your object. You might want to avoid LINQ and use a loop if `StringBuilder` is required (depending on the number of properties).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to iterate over all the properties of a particular type:

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, T>> PropertiesOfType<T>(object obj)
{
    return from p in obj.GetType().GetProperties()
            where p.PropertyType == typeof(T)
            select new KeyValuePair<string, T>(p.Name, (T)p.GetValue(obj));
}
```

Then you could specify the type as `string` for all your string properties.

Compilable sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var test = new Test
            {
                Str1 = "S1",
                Str2 = "S2",
                Str3 = "S3",
                Str4 = "S4"
            };

            foreach (var property in PropertiesOfType<string>(test))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(property.Key + ": " + property.Value);
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, T>> PropertiesOfType<T>(object obj)
        {
            return from p in obj.GetType().GetProperties()
                    where p.PropertyType == typeof(T)
                    select new KeyValuePair<string, T>(p.Name, (T)p.GetValue(obj));
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public string Str1 { get; set; }
        public string Str2 { get; set; }
        public string Str3 { get; set; }
        public string Str4 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is.

```
List<PropertyInfo> _propInfo = _row.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var item in _propInfo)
    {
    object _value = item.GetValue(_row, null);
    if (_value != null)
    {
    // Save the Value
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`GetProperties` returns an array of `PropertyInfo`, so use the `GetValue` method and use your object as it's input to get the value for each property. Here is the code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty3 { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
MyClass myObj = new MyClass() { MyProperty1 = "first", MyProperty2 = "second", MyProperty3 = "third" };

List<string> array = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in typeof(MyClass).GetProperties())
{
    array.Add(item.GetValue(myObj, null).ToString());
}

var result = string.Join(",", array); //use your own delimiter
```